# 3D animation on website

Tags: jquery, animation, 3d

First of all i am an undergraduate and for my third year project I am building an E-commerce spare parts web. For advanced searching i hope to include a vehicle image that is similar to following attachment and then upon the hovering of mouse over different parts of the vehicle image i need to pop up the particular part and then 'on click' i need to search for that particular part. Could you please suggest a way to achieve the above requirement. Do i need to use flash or can i do it with jquery? Thank you very much.

[image: This is Sample image of structure]

Answer (score 1):

You could use jQuery in combination with CSS animations. It is pretty simple jQuery because you simply add and remove classes. Here is a codepen I made for displaying different cards when clicked. http://codepen.io/sketchbookkeeper/pen/dpjPrK

Here is the basic idea starting with the CSS

```
 //CSS  for part after `open` class is added in jQuery
.part.open {
  animation-name: myAnimation;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  transform: scale(2,2);
  margin-top: 90px;
 }
 //CSS animation
 @keyframes myAnimation {
 //when the animation begins 
 0% {
   transform: scale(1,1);
   margin-top: 0px;
  }
  //when the animation is completed
  100% {
   transform: scale(2,2);
   margin-top: 90px;
  }
 }
```

In jQuery

```
$('.part').onclick = function () {
    if ($('.part).classList.contains('open')) {
       $(',part).remove('open');
    } else {
       $('.part').add('open');
    }
};
```

You could expand on this method to show or hide a search bar when a part is clicked. In my pen, I used jQuery to also center the card in the window.

Comment: thanks paul. But the thing is how can add these effect on to an image as in description. I mean one image divided with different parts.

Comment: I see, I would put all the image pieces in `<div>`s and arrange them properly. Then use the jQuery explained above to animate different parts You could also use the `<canvas>` element.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial 

I think that using the `<div>` method would be more web accessible.